# Error prohibited this category from being saved: Course must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Error prohibited this category from being saved:

> Course must exist

When I try to create a category there is one error telling course must exist but I have a created an entry in course table. what I'm I doing wrong?

Heres my `category.rb` code:

```
 class Category < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :course
 end
```

course.rb :

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category
  has_many :location
end
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
 t.text "details"
 t.integer "status", default: 0, null: false
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.string "alias"
  t.integer "category_id"
  t.date "start_date"
  t.date "end_date"
  t.integer "location_id"
  t.integer "max_participants"
  t.integer "min_participants"
  t.decimal "course_fee", default: "0.0"
  t.decimal "tax", default: "0.0"
  t.decimal "deposit", default: "0.0"
  t.text "description"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "if_fully_booked", default: 0
  t.text "short_description"
  t.integer "status", default: 0, null: false
  t.string "if_booked"
  t.string "currency"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `course_id` to `categories` table and you can do this like create a migration

```
rails g migration AddCourseIdToCategories course_id:integer
```

it will generate a migrate file like this

```
class AddCourseIdToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :categories, :course_id, :integer
  end
end
```

then `rake db:migrate`

or you can directly `reference` to `courses` like

```
rails g migration AddCourseToCategories course:references
```

it will generate a `db/migrate/TIMESTAMP_add_course_to_categories.rb` file like this

```
class AddCourseToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_reference :categories, :course, index: true
  end
end
```

then `rake db:migrate`

***Note:*** You can use `rake` or `rails` for migrating file. Since Rails `5.0+` has rake commands built into the rails executable, `rails` is the new default for running commands.

See [`The belongs_to Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)